# AVPlayer live stream video audio queue error

Tags: ios, video, avplayer

I manage to make a live stream video player. On good wifi, everything works great, but when on shoddy connection, I see this: `11:13:21.023 ERROR:    849: AudioQueue: request to trim 4291679171 + 0 = 4291679171 frames from buffer containing 23552 frames`. Then the video playback stalled. After awhile, the video continues to play without audio for a few seconds then everything is out of sync.

What I need is just to detect that error, then just reload the video (reselecting the same channel). I tried monitoring all the notification and KVO, nothing seems to properly detect that particular error. Closest one is the `AVPlayerItemNewErrorLogEntryNotification`, the *"Media file not received in 24s"* in particular. But it picks up 3-4 of those before that AudioQueue error pops up.